# how to implement the instagram login Oauth using javascript and java

Tags: java, javascript, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm new to Oauth and to instagram.I got register for the application and got client id, client secret, redirect url.I don't have any idea how to implement it.Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its not possible to authenticate Instagram Login.There are not still providing any API to authenticate an account with username and password credentials.You can authenticate your account by this request

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

You will get ClientID by 
[Register](http://instagram.com/developer/clients/register/)